# Axis to take when finding time period of oscillation after perturbing a dipole in an external electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Suppose I have sum of forces is zero, this means that torque is independent of the origin I take the torques around, but then there is a problem here, the inertia about any particular point is different. So, what point's inertia are we supposed to take when writing torque equation? To illustrate this issue, consider this problem:

> An electric dipole is formed by two equal and opposite charges q wit h a separation of d. The charges have the same mass equal to m. It is kept in a uniform electric field E. If it is slightly rotated from its equilibrium orientation, then its angular frequency is

For this question, so far I got $\vec{\tau} = qdE \sin \theta \hat{k}$ where the torque is perpendicular to the plane of dipole, but I can't figure out what would be the 'correct' axis to take inertia about to find the inertia about for calculating time period by the equation:

$$ I \alpha = qdE \sin \theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\alpha$ is $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$,  and $\sin\theta$ is approximately $\theta$ for small angles, looks as though you'll get S.H.M.

Just use the axis perpendicular to the field and the dipole, through the midpoint of the line connecting the charges and  $I = 2\times m{(\frac{d}{2})}^2$, where $m$ is the mass of the charges.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain why you took the inertia about midpoint of the dipole particularly? (In sense that you could have picked any other poitn on the plane but you choose that)

Comment: It seems like the easiest point to use.  Also angular momentum is conserved for central forces and if the forces between the charges themselves could make them move, it wouldn't matter for that point - but might lead to complications for other points.  But mainly it's just for convenience.

Comment: One more question, how did you conclude that you should take an axis perpendicular to field? It is an intuitive idea but I can't pin point exactly why it should be done

Comment: Hi Buraian,  It says it was rotated from it's equilibrium position (originally aligned with the field), the restoring torque would bring it directly back to it's equilibrium position.  The torque acts in the plane containing the original line of the dipole and the new line of the dipole...i.e the rotations all take place in that plane and the axis must be perpendicular to that, hope that makes sense.